# Extension of algebraic morphisms from a subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complex algebraic varieties and consider a subvariety of $X$ denoted by $Z$.  Let $f:Z\rightarrow Y$ be an algebraic morphism. We assume that $f$ admits an extension to the whole of $X$ as a continuous function i.e. there is a continuous (wrt analytic topology) function $F:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $F|_{Z}=f$. Now the question is when $f$ admits an algebraic extension to $X$? (when we can assume a function like $F$ exists and it is algebraic.)

Comment: Why would $f$ admit a continuous extension? Think of the case $Y=Z$, $f=$ identity.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly That is the assumption of the problem. I am not claiming it always does. There are certain obstructions for the topological extension. We are assuming those obstructions don't exist.

Comment: Certainly not true in general: take for $Z$ a point $p\in X$, there are plenty of continuous maps $X\rightarrow Y$ (with a given value at $p$) which are not algebraic.

Comment: @abx In that case assuming $p$ is getting mapped to the point $q$, isn't the constant map which maps the whole $X$ to $q$ algebraic?

Comment: An example where continuous extensions always exist but not algebraic extensions: $X=\mathbb{A}^1$, $Z=\{0,1\}$, $Y$ a curve of genus at least 1.

Comment: @JulianRosen In your example seems the issue is about being rationally connected. If we force this assumption does that resolve the problem?...

Comment: Oops, right, sorry — I assumed wrongly that you want $f$ itself to be algebraic.

Comment: @user127776: About Julian Rosen's example: you can also take for $X$ and $Y$ two non-isogenous elliptic curves.